# Unable to install easysnmp in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, snmp

I am using a Windows machine for Python development.

When I try to  `pip install easysnmp`

It throws an error:

```
Failed building wheel for easysnmp
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\infini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-r_bb9x\\easysnmp\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\infini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-0jzdkr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\infini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r_bb9x\easysnmp\
```

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual environment and try the following:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libperl-dev python-dev python-pip`

`cd /tmp`

`wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.3/net-snmp-5.7.3.tar.gz/`

`cd net-snmp*`

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

`download netsnmp and unpack it`

`sudo pip install easysnmp`

Comment: thanks for your help!
I have setup a VM of Linux and followed the steps.
after wget step when i try to go to cd net-snmp* it says no such directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 
On Debian / Ubuntu systems:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnmp-dev snmp-mibs-downloader
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev
```

then try

```
pip install easysnmp or pip3 install easysnmp
```